# $f$ is strictly increasing, $f (a) < a$, $ f(b) > b$. Number of solutions to $f(c) = c$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be a strictly monotonic continuous real valued function defined on $[a, b]$ such that $f (a) < a$ and $f(b) > b$.

My claim is that, $f(c)=c$ for $c \in (a,b)$, their is either exactly one such $c$ or infinitely many such $c's$.

How should I prove this?

Comment: That's false. Try to draw an increasing function which intersect $y=x$  exactly $3$ times.

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks i got that x³ works.

Comment: Use [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to show that at least one exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If your claim was true, some polynomials of degree three would have an infinite number of roots.